# Towers of Hanoi with Python, print each step by using list. but i don't want to use global variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

code explanation : input n is integer, other inputs are list(decreasing order). E.g., `n=3`, `A=list(range(n,0,-1))`, `B=[]`, `C=[]` (larger integer represent larger disc).

The fllowing code works, but input list variables (`start_`, `inter_`, `end_`) names must be `A`, `B`, `C` because Hanoi function includes global variable `A`, `B`, `C`. It's an annoying thing.

How can I represent each step with list without a global variable? In other word, How can operations (append, remove) of base case depend on input position not variable name.

For example:

`start_` is second input variable, `end_` is fourth input variable.

base case operation -> fourth input variable.append(second input variable[-1],
second input variable.remove(second input variable[-1])

```
def Hanoi(n,start_,inter_,end_):
    if n==1:
        end_.append(start_[-1])
        start_.remove(start_[-1])
        print('start_peg , inter_peg, end_peg :{}\t{}\t{}'.format(A,B,C))
    else:
        Hanoi(n-1,start_,end_,inter_)
        Hanoi(1,start_,inter_,end_)
        Hanoi(n-1,inter_,start_,end_)
n=3
A=list(range(n,0,-1))
B,C=[],[]
Hanoi(n,A,B,C) #variable name of three list input must be A,B,C


Out:
start_peg , inter_peg, end_peg :[3, 2]  []      [1]
start_peg , inter_peg, end_peg :[3]     [2]     [1]
start_peg , inter_peg, end_peg :[3]     [2, 1]  []
start_peg , inter_peg, end_peg :[]      [2, 1]  [3]
start_peg , inter_peg, end_peg :[1]     [2]     [3]
start_peg , inter_peg, end_peg :[1]     []      [3, 2]
start_peg , inter_peg, end_peg :[]      []      [3, 2, 1]
```

---- (start_,inter_,end_ )instead of (A,B,C) in fifth line ----

```
def Hanoi(n,start_,inter_,end_):
    if n==1:
        end_.append(start_[-1])
        start_.remove(start_[-1])
        print('start_peg , inter_peg, end_peg :{}\t{}\t{}'.format(start_,inter_,end_))
    else:
        Hanoi(n-1,start_,end_,inter_)
        Hanoi(1,start_,inter_,end_)
        Hanoi(n-1,inter_,start_,end_)

# it's possible to use any input variable name
n=3
a=list(range(n,0,-1))
b,c=[],[]
Hanoi(n,a,b,c)

Out:
start_peg , inter_peg, end_peg :[3, 2]  []      [1]
start_peg , inter_peg, end_peg :[3]     [1]     [2]
start_peg , inter_peg, end_peg :[]      [3]     [2, 1]
start_peg , inter_peg, end_peg :[]      [2, 1]  [3]
start_peg , inter_peg, end_peg :[2]     [3]     [1]
start_peg , inter_peg, end_peg :[]      [1]     [3, 2]
start_peg , inter_peg, end_peg :[]      []      [3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Use an inner function that you pass the list to.

Comment: How do you call this function? Also, why do you have A, B, C? You only use them in the print statement. Why don't you just print the lists you passed in, i.e., start_, inter_, end_?

Comment: Thanks for finally making the edits. Your question is quite clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list of lists and an optional argument to preserve the order of the three lists. This way you can always print them out the same way, while manipulating the items as needed by the algorithm:

```
def Hanoi(n,start_,inter_,end_, pegs=None):  # new optional argument
    if pegs is None:
        pegs = [start_, inter_, end_]  # build a list of lists if one was not passed in
    if n==1:
        end_.append(start_.pop()) # using pop makes this much easier
        print('start_peg , inter_peg, end_peg :{}\t{}\t{}'.format(*pegs)) # prints in order
    else:
        Hanoi(n-1,start_,end_,inter_, pegs) # pass on the list of lists in each recursive call
        Hanoi(1,start_,inter_,end_, pegs)   # this lets the original order be preserved
        Hanoi(n-1,inter_,start_,end_, pegs)
n=3
A=list(range(n,0,-1))
B,C=[],[]
Hanoi(n, A, B, C)
```

I made an incidental change to your code to call `list.pop` instead of indexing and then calling `remove` to get rid of the last item. This is more efficient (`O(1)` rather than `O(N)`), and much simpler as well!

The more important change is using a list of list `pegs` to preserve the order the three lists were in when the original call was made. That can be used by `print` to write them all out in a consistent order.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I represent each step with list without a global variable?

The answer is simple. Just use the names for the variables you passed in:

```
print('start_peg , inter_peg, end_peg :{}\t{}\t{}'.format(start_, inter_, end_))
```

That's how python works with objects. An object is bound to a name in a given scope, but if can be named in many scopes. You can bind an object to as many names as you like.

For example, let's say you have (outside the function)

```
n = 3
A = list(range(n, 0, -1))
B = []
C = []
```

The assignments bind four different objects (an `int` and three `list`s) to four different names (`n`, `A`, `B`, `C`) in the global namespace. Now when you call

```
Hanoi(n, A, B, C)
```

those same four objects get bound to the names `n`, `start_`, `inter_`, `end_` in the function's namespace. Whether you use the global name `A`, or the local name `start_`, you are referencing the same object in memory.

On an unrelated note, `start_.remove(start_[-1])` performs an unnecessary search by value for an object whose index you already know. Since you've already assigned the value to the correct stack on the line above, a much simpler way to do the removal would be

```
del start_[-1]
```

An even more elegant solution could be to replace both of those lines with

```
end_.append(start.pop())
```

Comment: Then you need to show all your code. How do you call the function?

Comment: For that matter, what output do you expect to see?

Comment: i already tried using local variable  '~~~~~'.format(start_,inter_,end_).
when i use " '~~~~~'.format(start_,inter_,end_)" , i found printed lists position is wrong.
if you run two codes , you will notice the difference clearly.

Comment: i call the function (code containing global variable  A,B,C)---> n=2, A=list(range(n,0,-1)),B=[],C=[] 

Hanoi(n,A,B,C)

Comment: Show the full code, and explain exactly what your are seeing. Explain how that that differs from what you expect. Do it by editing your question. Code in the comments is effectively illegible.

Comment: In output of second function of Hanoi using (start_,inter_,end_) instead of global variable(A,B,C)
disk '1' change its position abruptly in second output line. in that case, second code don't represent step by step procedure. Because base case operation (end_.append, start_.remove) operates on local variable name not their position.
my intention for the base case is position-dependent operation.

Hanoi(first variable(1(=base case)),second(?), third(?), fourth(?)) means
that' Move the disk(second[-1]) from second to fourth peg. 
(? : start_,inter_,end_  position can be changed).

Answer (score -1):

You can "name" the lists using the first element:

```
n=3, A=["A"]+list(range(n,0,-1)), B=["B"], C=["C"]
```

and modify the print statement:

```
print('start_peg , inter_peg, end_peg :{}\t{}\t{}'.format( *sorted((start_, inter_, end_)) ))
```

The sorting will take effect on "A","B","C".

**EDIT:**
If you don't like the solution above, you can create a new class:

```
class Hanoi:

    def __init__(self,start_):
        self.n= len(start_)
        self.A,self.B,self.C= start_,[],[]


    def go(self):
        self.Hanoi(self.n,self.A,self.B,self.C)


    def Hanoi(self,n,start_,inter_,end_): # <--- your code
         if n==1:
             end_.append(start_[-1])
             start_.remove(start_[-1])
             print(self)
         else:
             self.Hanoi(n-1,start_,end_,inter_)
             self.Hanoi(1,start_,inter_,end_)
             self.Hanoi(n-1,inter_,start_,end_)

    def __str__(self):
       return 'start_peg, inter_peg, end_peg :{}\t{}\t{}'.format(self.A,self.B,self.C)

    def get_pegs(self):
       return self.A,self.B,self.C


#h=Hanoi(list(range(3,0,-1)))
h=Hanoi([3,2,1])
h.go()
A,B,C= h.get_pegs()
print(A,B,C)

Out:
start_peg, inter_peg, end_peg :[3, 2]   []  [1]
start_peg, inter_peg, end_peg :[3]  [2] [1]
start_peg, inter_peg, end_peg :[3]  [2, 1]  []
start_peg, inter_peg, end_peg :[]   [2, 1]  [3]
start_peg, inter_peg, end_peg :[1]  [2] [3]
start_peg, inter_peg, end_peg :[1]  []  [3, 2]
start_peg, inter_peg, end_peg :[]   []  [3, 2, 1]
[] [] [3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks. it's more general than my code. 
But this change is forced to use particular input format. 
Is it possible to use lists which only contain numbers?